# What is the difference between romanticism and existentialism?

Tags: terminology, fyodor-dostoyevsky, alexander-pushkin

It seems existentialism and romanticism are both literary movements which (1) see a man as irrational,  and  (2) search for meaning in an individual's life. Can we say that these movements are essentially the same, but happened in different times? For example, is authenticity of an individual equally important to both?

Can we say that Pushkin was existentialist, the same as Dostoyevsky?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, it would help to know a bit about the context of the class in which it was given.

Comment: @cmw This is an independent research. I am trying to place somewhere "Little tragedies" by Pushkin. In my view, they fit in the Kierkegaard 's type of existentialism nicely. But how did Pushkin get it? If there is no big difference between Kierkegaard and Romanticism it would explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the background. There is a huge difference between the two, but I do find it interesting how you highlighted the two connected points. I'm not an expert on this topic, so I'll sit it out for now and maybe offer up some thoughts if no one answers you soon.

Comment: Both "Existentialism" and "Romanticism" are very wide terms with lots of different meanings. The romanticism of Goethe is very different to that of Poe or  Shelley. It makes more sense to say so-and-so had some existentialist elements, rather than saying they were an existentialist (after all, even Kierkegaard was a Christian above being an existentialist). Asking "do they have equal focus" or "are they essentially the same" is difficult because of this variety: some romanticism focuses on the individual while other is far more political or social, but still has other romantic traits.

Comment: @Stuart I asked what is the difference. If it was easy, I would not ask.

Comment: Here is a good answer to your question: https://philosophyisnotaluxury.com/2010/08/romanticism-and-existential-philosophy/

Comment: Thank you. The text seems a bit superficial. " Romantics had a tendency to reach backward in an attempt to regain the spirit that they believed had been lost, while the Existentialists called for a stark confrontation with the fact that humanity had grown beyond the old sources of security".  Dostoyevsky believed in God. There is no reaching back among Russian romanticists at all. (Goethe did not reach back for an ideal either, as far as I know. ) So, the features he picked up do not help to place Pushkin or anybody Russian.

Comment: This post appears to contain two questions: one about the difference between romanticism and existentialism, and one about Puskin and Dostoyevski. On Stack Exchange, a single post is expected to focus on a single question. In addition, the first question can be answered without answering the second question. So could you move "Can we say that Pushkin was existentialist, the same as Dostoyevsky?" to a separate post?

Comment: Pushkin and Dostoyevsky are examples of a Romanticist and Existentialist.

Comment: Does not matter what you do with the question, it does not appear like I will get an answer.

Comment: Marina, you are much more likely to get an answer when you focus the post on just the first question and move the second one to a separate post. I have been reading about romanticism and existentialism to prepare an answer to the first question.

Comment: If you can answer the first question, it would answer the second one for me. If the examples of Pushkin and Dostoyevsky are not helpful, ignore them.

Comment: "If you can answer the first question, it would answer the second one for me." In that case, please move the second question to a separate post.

Comment: This is not a question. This is an example. Thank you.

Comment: "Pushkin and Dostoyevsky are examples of a Romanticist and Existentialist." In a [previous comment](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22876/which-literary-movement-do-pushkins-little-tragedies-belong-to#comment34399_22876) you wrote, "This is a tradition of Russian literary critique: to consider everything Pushkin wrote after 1825 as realism." So was Pushkin a romantic, a realist or an existentialist? Or all of them? At different period during his literary activity?

Comment: Pushkin was Pushkin. Russian tradition is like I explained. I do not believe this division is correct. In particularly, I do not believe Pushkin was a "realist" ever. His earlier poems, up until 1825, are more similar to other romantic poems, than what he wrote after that. I believe, Pushkin started a new literary movement. And among his followers was Dostoyevsky.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Both Romanticism and Existentialism are movements, meaning they characterize some fashion, prevalent worldview of certain time period. Romanticism is associated more with art, while Existentialism is associated with philosophy. Both terms characterize the respective time period. The terms are rather vague. For example, we read in Wikipedia^ "The labels existentialism and existentialist are often seen as historical conveniences in as much as they were first applied to many philosophers long after they had died." If we consider main ideas of these two movements, we see lots of common themes between them. First of all, they  both belong to irrationalism.  And this complex of ideas comes from ancient East and from European Antiquity (see Socrates, for example). These ideas are perennial, but every new follower adds something new to them. The difference between two existentialists (like Nietzsche and Kierkegaard) may be bigger than a difference between an existentialist and a romanticist. So, to understand a writer, it may be less helpful to identify the movement where he belongs, than to identify his prevalent worldview, main ideas. Both Pushkin and Dostoevsky, for example,  did not fit in a particular movement, a particular thought fashion. They both were trailblazers, not followers of a fashion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Anonymous downrating  without any explanation makes the community to look even worse than an absence of an answer on a reasonable question.

Comment: I answered my question, you did not. Now, you can go ahead with your "powerful" downgrading. What else can you do at this point?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but I can't help noticing that the flaws in your go deeper than the lack for supporting information pointed out by the first comment. One issue is the oversimplified presentation of both romanticism and existentialism; another is the non-sequitur "both reacted against rationalism so they belong to irrationalism" (assuming that only two positions exist rather than a wide range between two extremes). In addition, the claim that romanticism was influenced by the "ancient East" does not convince me at all.

Comment: "One issue is the oversimplified presentation of both romanticism and existentialism; another is the non-sequitur "both reacted against rationalism so they belong to irrationalism" "

Comment: "One issue is the oversimplified presentation... " My goal was not to explain you anything, or convince you.  I answered my own question after long and thorough consideration. Irrationalism mentioned in the question, and nobody objected to it. The answer, essentially, is that the difference is in their time periods, therefore there is no need to go deeper in their distinction, since exact definitions do not exist. The movements developed naturally, not to fit any predetermined definition.

Comment: Overall, I found this community rather abusive and not helpful at all.